# why is nvidia installing gnome?

Tags: nvidia, i3-wm

I'm working on a barebone install of Ubuntu with i3wm.

now I wanted to install nvidia drivers and after reboot I got an login manager and a gnome desktop.

why did nvidia install that?

is there any way I can get drivers without these?

Edit:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
```

is what i did

Comment: You haven't provided any specifics (eg. what nvidia package, from where) you installed that created your issue.  If you look up dependencies, you may discover an installed package requires other packages installed so they'll be pulled in to, all of which can be discovered prior to install - so if it was done it meant you didn't check dep.rules. We can't provide more without specifics.

Comment: @guiverc I added the information I checked /var/log/apt/history.log and there are a lot of gnome packages from the nvidia install

Comment: I still don't know your release (which is used to look up dependencies; if I guess a different release answers could be wrong for you), and as a 3rd party PPA, Ubuntu online package-tools won't know of it, and I can't look up using command line as I don't have the PPA installed (nor want to validate 3rd party..).   Either way you are asked prior to install to approve it - why did you if you didn't want it? look up why then? (given you know your release, had the PPA installed so can look up easier than I can)

Comment: @guiverc how else should I install nvidia drivers if not with a 3rd party ppa?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Installing the nvidia* packages from the ppa didn't cause anything different to haapen than would have via Ubuntu repo's. Ay suggestion it did is ill-informed. If you can install and run synaptic then see what display manger is installed (lightdm or gdm3) and if any *sessions are installed like gnome-session, ubuntu-session, ect.